# Xamarin, ListView, How can I find out when ListView is scrolled to the middle?

Tags: listview, events, xamarin.forms, scroll

I want to call one method when the ListView is scrolled to the middle.

I have the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView">
...
</ListView>
```

This ListView have a subscriber

```
myListView.Scrolled += ScrolledListener;
```

The myListView.Scrolled listener:

```
public void ScrolledListener(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs args)
{
...
var scrollView = (ListView)sender;
bool isNeededMoreParticipants =
 args.ScrollY >
 (int)(scrollView.Height - scrollView.Height / 2); //Height - is not what I expected. I need the maximum size of ScrollY
...
}
```

How can I find out when ListView is scrolled to the middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the content size of ListView . You could set the height of `ViewCell` or `RowHeight` in advance (set as a static value or use data binding) like

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" Scrolled="ListView_Scrolled" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" RowHeight="60">
```

Or

```
<DataTemplate>

   <ViewCell>

      <StackLayout HeightRequest="{Binding xxx}">



      </StackLayout>

   </ViewCell>

</DataTemplate>
```

And in code behind

```
private void ListView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
   var rowHeight = MyListView.RowHeight;  // you need to set it in xaml in advance , otherwise it will always -1 .If you bind the height in code behind , use the height instead of it

   double contentHeight = rowHeight * MyItems.Count;  // content height of listview

   double positionY = e.ScrollY;

   // if(...) handle your logic 
}
```